# Frame rate 120fps, new iPad Pro: Enable how?

Tags: sprite-kit, frame-rate

Is it possible to enable and play/run at 120Hz on the new iPad Pros with Sprite Kit?

If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2460/_index.html

You pretty much need to allow custom frame rates by setting `CADisableMinimumFrameDuration = true` in your `Info.plist`

(This should not be needed in future updates,  not sure if iOS 11 already did these changes)

Then you change your View's frame rate with:

```
let maxFPS = UIScreen.maximumFramesPerSecond

preferredFramesPerSecond = maxFPS
```

Comment: let maxFPS = UIScreen.main.maximumFramesPerSecond

Comment: Yes, it changed sometime after this answer